# OpenCV: Remove the background noise for Tesseract OCR

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have a drone FPV video, from which I need extract GPS coordinates. The text is white, but because of bad quality of video it seems gray and light blue. Since the background is changing, I have some problems, because in some frames the background has a totally different and in some frames a similar color to the text one.

Here is 2 original images (frames) from the video:

1. Dark background [image: Dark background]
2. Light background [image: Light background]

And here is the code that I've found after googling:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pytesseract

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('v1.avi')

p = 10000
while(cap.isOpened()):

    ret, frame = cap.read()

    img = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img = img[380:460, 220:640]

    img = cv2.bilateralFilter(img, 9, 27, 27)

    img = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255,
                        cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (9, 9), 0)
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 3))
    img = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_TOPHAT, kernel)
    img = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel)
    img = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 250, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

    cv2.imshow('frame', img)
    cv2.imshow('or', frame)

    print('\n==============')
    print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config='digits'))
    if cv2.waitKey(50) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And also the results:

1. Dark background [image: Dark background]
2. Light background [image: Light background]

As you can see, in the second case the background isn't clear, there is some noise, and from that image Tesseract doesn't extract the text properly.

EDIT:
For some reasons I can't share the video I wrote about above, but [here is a similar video from Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TmXh9golh3Y), and if the text can be extracted from that video, I guess that method will also work for mine or solve many problems at least:

[image: Similar video from Youtube]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get something working using a combination of `cv2.bilateralFilter` and `cv2.adaptiveThreshold`. Once the background is in one main blob, the numbers can be extracted based on their patch sizes.

```
img = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Bilaterial filter and adaptive histogram thresholding to get background into mostly one patch
img = cv2.bilateralFilter(img, 9, 29, 29)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 13, 0)

# Add padding to join any background around edges into the same patch 
pad = 2
img_pad = cv2.copyMakeBorder(thresh, pad, pad, pad, pad, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value = 1)

# Label patches and remove padding
ret, markers = cv2.connectedComponents(img_pad)
markers = markers[pad:-pad,pad:-pad]

# Count pixels in each patch
counts = [(markers==i).sum() for i in range(markers.max()+1)]

# Keep patches based on pixel counts
maxCount = 200 # removes large background patches
minCount = 40  # removes specs and centres of numbering
keep = [c<maxCount and c>minCount for c in counts]
output = markers.copy()
for i,k in enumerate(keep):
    output[markers==i] = k
```

Here is what the images look like at each stage.

[image: Image showing each stage of the analysis]

Comment: This method really works for two images I posted above, but sadly there are many frames where it fails and as a result Tesseract fails too. Doing some filtering for OCR results, I managed to get the correct (or with 1 digit wrong) text every 3-4 seconds, but I think the result should be improved, because now Tesseract recognizes 3 either as 9 or as 3, and the filtering doesn't help because the cases are equally possible. Unfortunately I'm not allowed to share the video, from which the text need to be extracted, but I've edited my question and included a similar video.